# Using z3 api to solve LRA runs slower than use z3 in terminal

Tags: c, z3, smt

I am trying to use Z3 to solve a random generalized strip-packing problem(LRA) and I call Z3 api in a c program, here is the code.

```
Z3_context ctx;
Z3_ast fs;
LOG_MSG("smt2parser_example");
FILE *fp = fopen("smttest","r");  
if(fp == NULL)  
{
    perror("fopen()");
    return;
}
int file_size;
fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
file_size = ftell( fp );

char *tmp;
fseek( fp , 0 , SEEK_SET);
tmp =  (char *)malloc( (file_size+1) * sizeof( char ) );
tmp[file_size]='\0';
fread( tmp , file_size , sizeof(char) , fp);

ctx = mk_context();
fs  = Z3_parse_smtlib2_string(ctx, tmp, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Z3_assert_cnstr(ctx, fs);

Z3_model m      = 0;

Z3_check(ctx);

Z3_del_context(ctx);
```

I also try to solve smttest in terminal by command "z3 smttest". However, in terminal , it runs faster than calling api in c program. I wonder is there any configuration I need to set to make it run fast in api mode?(by the way, z3 runs two times faster in terminal than calling an api.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function "Z3_assert_cnstr(ctx, fs);" is no longer available, so you must be using a very old version of Z3. Use the "solver" objects to assert expressions, and also use the C++ API for improved reliability. You can create solvers for specified logics, such as "QF_LRA", in which case the initial setup is forced to be appropriate for that logic. By default Z3 will try to automatically find good settings by analyzing the asserted formulas before the first check-sat.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I create a solver for  "QF_LRA" logic and this problems was solved.